# Simple injector open generic decorators

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, ioc-container, simple-injector

I am trying to make use of some of the nice features in simple injector.

I am currently having problems with the decorators, they are not getting hit when I expect them too.

I am registering them like this:

```cs
container.RegisterManyForOpenGeneric(
      typeof(ICommandHandler<>),
      AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());

container.RegisterDecorator(
      typeof(ICommandHandler<>),
      typeof(CreateValidFriendlyUrlCommandHandler<>),
      context => context.ServiceType == typeof(ICommandHandler<CreateProductCommand>)
 );

 container.RegisterDecorator(
      typeof(ICommandHandler<>),
      typeof(CreateProductValidationCommandHandler<>),
      context => context.ServiceType == typeof(ICommandHandler<CreateProductCommand>)
 );
```

I think I must be missing something as I am expecting that a call to `ICommandHandler<CreateProductCommand>` will invoke `CreateValidFriendlyUrlCommandHandler<>` and `CreateProductValidationCommandHandler<>` before running itself.

I have tried a different registration like this:

```cs
container.RegisterManyForOpenGeneric(
      typeof(ICommandHandler<>),
      AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());

container.RegisterDecorator(
      typeof(ICommandHandler<>),
      typeof(CreateValidFriendlyUrlCommandHandler<>),
      context => context.ImplementationType == typeof(CreateProductCommandHandler)
 );

 container.RegisterDecorator(
      typeof(ICommandHandler<>),
      typeof(CreateProductValidationCommandHandler<>),
      context => context.ImplementationType == typeof(CreateProductCommandHandler)
 );
```

As I thought registering a decorator for `ICommandHandler<CreateProductCommand>` on the type `ICommandHandler<CreateProductCommand>` when the `CreateProductValidationCommandHandler` and `CreateValidFriendlyUrlCommandHandler` implement `ICommandHandler<CreateProductCommand>` may well hit a bit of a circular reference.

But changing that made no difference.

Here is my `CreateProductValidationCommandHandler<TCommand>`:

```cs
public class CreateProductValidationCommandHandler<TCommand> 
    : ICommandHandler<CreateProductCommand>
{
    private readonly ICommandHandler<TCommand> decorated;
    private readonly IValidationService validationService;

    public CreateProductValidationCommandHandler(
        ICommandHandler<TCommand> decorated,
        IValidationService validationService)
    {
        this.decorated = decorated;
        this.validationService = validationService;
    }

    public void Handle(CreateProductCommand command)
    {
        if (!validationService.IsValidFriendlyName(
            command.Product.ProductFriendlyUrl))
        {
            command.ModelStateDictionary.AddModelError(
                "ProductFriendlyUrl", 
                "The Friendly Product Name is not valid...");

            return;
        }

        if (!validationService.IsUniqueFriendlyName(
            command.Product.ProductFriendlyUrl))
        {
            command.ModelStateDictionary.AddModelError(
                "ProductFriendlyUrl", 
                "The Friendly Product Name is ...");

            return;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my `CreateValidFriendlyUrlCommandHandler<TCommand>`:

```
public class CreateValidFriendlyUrlCommandHandler<TCommand>
    : ICommandHandler<CreateProductCommand>
{
    private readonly ICommandHandler<TCommand> decorated;

    public CreateValidFriendlyUrlCommandHandler(ICommandHandler<TCommand> decorated)
    {
        this.decorated = decorated;
    }

    public void Handle(CreateProductCommand command)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(
            command.Product.ProductFriendlyUrl))
        {
            command.Product.ProductFriendlyUrl = 
                MakeFriendlyUrl(command.Product.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your decorators should not be generic. In fact, they are technically no decorators :-)

Comment: Please note that `Appdomain.CurrentDomain.GeAssemblies` only returns assemblies that are already loaded. If all implementations are in the same assembly as `ICommandHandler<T>` it won't be a problem, but otherwise be careful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that Simple Injector will never be able to wrap an `ICommandHandler<T>` implementation with one of your decorators, because there is an unresolvable generic type `TCommand`. You would have noticed this if the `Handle` method of your decorators would call the `decorated` instance. For instance:

```
public class CreateValidFriendlyUrlCommandHandler<TCommand>
    : ICommandHandler<CreateProductCommand>
{
    private readonly ICommandHandler<TCommand> decorated;

    public CreateValidFriendlyUrlCommandHandler(
        ICommandHandler<TCommand> decorated)
    {
        this.decorated = decorated;
    }

    public void Handle(CreateProductCommand command)
    {
        // This won't compile since CreateProductCommand and
        // TCommand are not related.
        this.decorated.Handle(command);
    }
}
```

This code won't compile, since the decorator's `Handle` method takes an `CreateProductCommand` argument, while the `decorated` instance takes a `TCommand` argument, which isn't specified (and nowhere is stated that `CreateProductCommand` is a `TCommand`).

In fact you didn't create a decorator at all. A decorator wraps an instance of the same interface that it implements. You wrap an `ICommandHandler<TCommand>` while you implement an `ICommandHandler<CreateProductCommand>`. The only way you would get this to work is when you explicitly specify the `TCommand` to be a `CreateProductCommand`, as follows:

```
ICommandHandler<CreateProductCommand> handler = 
    new CreateValidFriendlyUrlCommandHandler<CreateProductCommand>(
        new CreateProductCommandHandler()
    );
```

Still, there is no way for Simple Injector to 'guess' that this `TCommand` should be a `CreateProductCommand` and that's why your 'decorator' didn't get wrapped.

Long story short: ditch the `TCommand`:

```
public class CreateValidFriendlyUrlCommandHandler
    : ICommandHandler<CreateProductCommand>
{
    private ICommandHandler<CreateProductCommand> decorated;

    public CreateValidFriendlyUrlCommandHandler(
        ICommandHandler<CreateProductCommand> decorated)
    {
        this.decorated = decorated;
    }

    public void Handle(CreateProductCommand command)
    {
        // logic here
    }
}
```

Or make it generic with a type constraint:

```
   public class CreateValidFriendlyUrlCommandHandler<TCommand>
        : ICommandHandler<TCommand>
        where TCommand : CreateProductCommand
    {
        private ICommandHandler<TCommand> decorated;

        public CreateValidFriendlyUrlCommandHandler(
            ICommandHandler<TCommand> decorated)
        {
            this.decorated = decorated;
        }

        public void Handle(TCommand command)
        {
            // logic here
        }
    }
```

or remove the type constraint and allow handling any type of command, not only `CreateProductCommand`.

Note that if you are defining many decorators that can only handle one specific type of command handler, you might want to reconsider your strategy. There might be a problem in your design.

Comment: OK that makes sense, some of what I have was me trying to get it working as I want. I have an open generic registration and want some decorators but I only want them applied when the command is a specific type. It seems Ive gone about it in the wrong way though. Thanks :)

Comment: Now that I am awake I had another go at it, once I stopped using RegisterManyForOpenGeneric and ditched TCommand as suggested I now have it working :)

Comment: @DavidMcLean: There is no reason to stop using `RegisterManyForOpenGeneric` since this registers all implementations of an open generic interface in one go. There's no good alternative for that.

Comment: @DavidMcLean: Also note that I think you managed to slip through the argument validation process of the `RegisterDecorator` method. I'm currently looking at improving this so an `ArgumentException` is thrown instead of silently accepting the type but never be able to wrap a type. So thanks for bringing this question up.

Comment: RE `RegisterManyForOpenGeneric` - I was having a problem because I have more than one implementation for ICommandHandler<CreateProductCommand> and rightly so it is only expecting one. A lot of what I did above was to try and work around this error. Once I accepted that I can just register the implementation I wanted and then decorate it I got to a working solution very quickly.

Comment: More info here: http://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Advanced-scenarios#Batch_Registration

Comment: I'm currently [working on a fix](http://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/workitem/18956) that prevents a user from registering these invalid types. It will be fixed in the next version. In the meantime.... don't register them ;-)

Comment: ;-) I will be sure to avoid doing so - Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I am trying a sample using simpleinjector and did the setup like this. But I don't know how to get the right handler for any given command at runtime. please help.