# Register decorator with another dependency of same generic type

Tags: c#, .net, generics, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I think I have stumbled upon a quirk in Simple Injector's `RegisterDecorator()`. It occurs even in the most recent 2.5.0. I have a situation where I want to decorate a closed generic type, for example `ICommandHandler<MessageCommand>`, with a decorator that takes (via constructor injection) an inner handler of type `ICommandHandler<MessageCommand>`, but also another type of handler, say `ICommandHandler<LogCommand>`. Even though these command handler types are distinct, SimpleInjector seems to get confused and throws an exception when I call `RegisterDecorator` on such a decorator type:

> ArgumentException: For the container to be able to use MessageLogger as a decorator, its constructor must include a single parameter of type `ICommandHandler<MessageCommand>` (or `Func<ICommandHandler<MessageCommand>>`) - i.e. the type of the instance that is being decorated. The parameter type `ICommandHandler<MessageCommand>` is defined multiple times in the constructor of class MessageLogger.

... even though the decorator clearly only has one `ICommandHandler<MessageCommand>` parameter.

Here is the full working example that throws the exception:

```
public interface ICommandHandler<T>
{
    void Execute(T command);
}

public class LogCommand
{
    public string LogMessage { get; set; }
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
}

public class Logger : ICommandHandler<LogCommand>
{
    public void Execute(LogCommand command)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Message \"{0}\" sent at {1}",
            command.LogMessage, command.Time));
    }
}


public class MessageCommand
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
}

public class MessageSender : ICommandHandler<MessageCommand>
{
    public void Execute(MessageCommand command)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(command.Message);
    }
}

// message command handler decorator that logs about messages being sent
public class MessageLogger : ICommandHandler<MessageCommand>
{
    private ICommandHandler<MessageCommand> innerHandler;
    private ICommandHandler<LogCommand> logger;

    // notice these dependencies are two distinct closed generic types
    public MessageLogger(ICommandHandler<MessageCommand> innerHandler,
        ICommandHandler<LogCommand> logger)
    {
        this.innerHandler = innerHandler;
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    public void Execute(MessageCommand command)
    {
        innerHandler.Execute(command);

        var logCommand = new LogCommand
            {
                LogMessage = command.Message,
                Time = DateTime.Now
            };
        logger.Execute(logCommand);
    }
}

// this works as intended, but is tedious in a real-world app
ICommandHandler<MessageCommand> ResolveManually()
{
    ICommandHandler<MessageCommand> sender = new MessageSender();
    ICommandHandler<LogCommand> logger = new Logger();

    ICommandHandler<MessageCommand> loggerSender =
        new MessageLogger(sender, logger);

    return loggerSender;
}

// this is what I want to work - seems simple?
ICommandHandler<MessageCommand> ResolveWithSimpleInjector()
{
    var container = new Container();

    container.Register<ICommandHandler<LogCommand>, Logger>();

    container.Register<ICommandHandler<MessageCommand>, MessageSender>();

    // this next line throws the exception
    container.RegisterDecorator(typeof(ICommandHandler<MessageCommand>),
        typeof(MessageLogger));

    return container.GetInstance<ICommandHandler<MessageCommand>>();
}

void Main()
{
    //ICommandHandler<MessageCommand> sender = ResolveManually();
    ICommandHandler<MessageCommand> sender = ResolveWithSimpleInjector();

    var command = new MessageCommand { Message = "Hello World!" };
    sender.Execute(command);
}
```

I could not find any information about this situation. Is this a bug, or am I missing something?

**Edit**

I am fishing for feedback from a dev on SimpleInjector to find out if there is a technical reason for this limitation, or it is something that was overlooked... Unless someone can convince me there is a logical flaw in this design and there is a good reason I shouldn't do things this way, which none of the answers thus far have been able to do. I do appreciate the feedback.

It seems to me that the core issue is that `RegisterDecorator()` is treating two different closed generic types as the same type. There may be a technical reason for this based on its inner workings, but maybe not?

Comment: Simple Injector 2.7 has removed this limitation and it is now possible to do this. Still, in the case of registration of generic decorators, this will only work if either the decorator contains generic type constraints, or the decorator is registered with a filter predicate. Otherwise, Simple Injector will almost certainly throw a “cyclic dependency detected” exception.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I had to do some investigation in the code base to see what was going one. You might call this a glitch in Simple Injector's implementation, but it's IMO a fair trade off. Simple Injector's decorator sub system is based around the idea of working with open generic types and open generic decorators. The check it does upon decorator registration is to see if a decorator's constructor has only one decoratee. This check is done using the open generic abstraction to which the decorator must be applied; in your case `ICommandHandler<T>`. Since at that point only the generic `ICommandHandler<T>` is available, two constructor parameters match this type.

It is possible to improve these pre-condition checks, but this is actually quite nasty, while the usefulness of this feature is very limited. It's limited because it's only useful for non-generic decorators. Take a look at the following decorator for instance:

```
public class GenericDecorator<TCommand> : ICommandHandler<TCommand> {
    public GenericDecorator(
        ICommandHandler<TCommand> decoratee,
        ICommandHandler<LoggingCommand> dependency)
    {
    }
}
```

This decorator is generic and allows you to apply it to any decorator, which is much more useful. But what happens when you resolve an `ICommandHandler<LoggingCommand>`? That would cause a cyclic dependency graph and Simple Injector will (obviously) not be able to create that graph and will throw an exception. It must throw, since the decorator will in that case have two `ICommandHandler<LoggingCommand>` arguments. The first will be the decoratee and will be injected with your `Logger`, and the second will be a normal dependency and will be injected with a `GenericDecorator<LoggingCommand>`, which is recursive of course.

So I would argue that the problem is in your design. In general I advice against composing command handlers out of other command handlers. The `ICommandHandler<T>` should be the abstraction that lies on top of your business layer that defines how the presentation layer communicates with the business layer. It's not a mechanism for the business layer to use internally. If you start doing this, your dependency configuration becomes very complicated. Here's an example of a graph that uses `DeadlockRetryCommandHandlerDecorator<T>` and a `TransactionCommandHandlerDecorator<T>`:

```
new DeadlockRetryCommandHandlerDecorator<MessageCommand>(
    new TransactionCommandHandlerDecorator<MessageCommand>(
        new MessageSender()))
```

In this case the `DeadlockRetryCommandHandlerDecorator<T>` and a `TransactionCommandHandlerDecorator<T>` are applied to the `MessageSender` command handler. But look what happens we apply your `MessageLogger` decorator as well:

```
new DeadlockRetryCommandHandlerDecorator<MessageCommand>(
    new TransactionCommandHandlerDecorator<MessageCommand>(
        new MessageLogger(
            new MessageSender(),
            new DeadlockRetryCommandHandlerDecorator<MessageLogger>(
                new TransactionCommandHandlerDecorator<MessageLogger>(
                    new Logger())))))
```

Notice how there's a second `DeadlockRetryCommandHandlerDecorator<T>` and a second `TransactionCommandHandlerDecorator<T>` in the object graph. What does it mean to have a transaction in a transaction and have a nested deadlock retry (within a transaction). This can cause serious reliability problems in your application (since a database deadlock will cause your [operation to continue in a transaction-less connection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2257670/264697)).

Although it is possible to create your decorators in such way that they are able to detect that they are nested to make them work correctly in case they're nested, this makes implementing them much harder and much more fragile. IMO that's a waste of your time.

So instead of allowing command handlers to be nested, let command handlers and command handler decorators depend upon other abstractions. In your case, the problem can be easily fixed by changing your decorator by letting it use an `ILogger` interface of some sort:

```
public class MessageLogger : ICommandHandler<MessageCommand> {
    private ICommandHandler<MessageCommand> innerHandler;
    private ILogger logger;

    public MessageLogger(
        ICommandHandler<MessageCommand> innerHandler, ILogger logger) {
        this.innerHandler = innerHandler;
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    public void Execute(MessageCommand command) {
        innerHandler.Execute(command);

        logger.Log(command.Message);
    }
}
```

You can still have an `ICommandHandler<LogCommand>` implementation in case the presentation layer needs to log directly, but in that case that implementation can simply depend on that `ILogger` as well:

```
public class LogCommandHandler : ICommandHandler<LogCommand> {
    private ILogger logger;

    public LogCommandHandler(ILogger logger) {
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    public void Execute(LogCommand command) {
        logger(string.Format("Message \"{0}\" sent at {1}",
            command.LogMessage, DateTime.Now));
    }
}
```

Comment: Accepted for not only explanation of library code, but the for the explanation of the best application of decorators and `ICommandHandler<T>`. Thank you for taking the time to make such an in-depth answer. While I could leave my design as is, I will be change my logging interface in my real app to a non-command handler.

Answer (score 2):

This is an edge case that you could possibly argue either way but the fact is that Simple Injector explicitly does not support what you are trying to do.

A decorator would normally be required to apply common logic across all (or some) of a particular abstraction, which in your example is `ICommandHandler`. In other words `MessageLogger` is designed to decorate `ICommandHandler`'s and as it is a decorator of `ICommandHandler`'s it can only take one `ICommandHandler` in it's constructor. In addition, allowing something like this would require reams of horrible circular checks that are best avoided with a cleaner design!

As such you would normally define a decorator with the same interface (and generic parameters) as the type it is decorating

```
public class MessageLogger<TCommand> : ICommandHandler<TCommand>
    where TCommand : <some criteria e.g. MessageCommand>
{
    //....
}
```

The first solution I can think of to mitigate your problem is create a mediator to remove the direct dependency:

```
public class LoggerMediator
{
    private readonly ICommandHandler<LogCommand> logger;

    public LoggerMediator(ICommandHandler<LogCommand> logger)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    public void Execute(LogCommand command)
    {
        this.logger.Execute(command);
    }
}
```

And change your `MessageLogger` to use the mediator.

```
public class MessageLogger<TCommand> : ICommandHandler<TCommand>
    where TCommand : MessageCommand
{
    private ICommandHandler<TCommand> innerHandler;
    private LoggerMediator logger;

    public MessageLogger(
        ICommandHandler<TCommand> innerHandler,
        LoggerMediator logger)
    {
        this.innerHandler = innerHandler;
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    public void Execute(TCommand command)
    {
        innerHandler.Execute(command);

        var logCommand = new LogCommand
        {
            LogMessage = command.Message,
            Time = DateTime.Now
        };
        logger.Execute(logCommand);
    }
}
```

BTW you can simplify your registrations like this

```
var container = new Container();
container.RegisterManyForOpenGeneric(
    typeof(ICommandHandler<>), 
    typeof(ICommandHandler<>).Assembly);
container.Register<LoggerMediator>();
container.RegisterDecorator(typeof(ICommandHandler<>), typeof(MessageLogger<>));
container.Verify();
```

---

**UPDATE**

Looking through my code base here I have found that I have had a similar requirement and I resolved it with one extra class - a generic command mediator:

```
public class CommandHandlerMediator<TCommand>
{
    private readonly ICommandHandler<TCommand> handler;

    public CommandHandlerMediator(ICommandHandler<TCommand> handler)
    {
        this.handler = handler;
    }

    public void Execute(TCommand command)
    {
        this.handler.Execute(command);
    }
}
```

registered like this:

```
container.RegisterOpenGeneric(
    typeof(CommandHandlerMediator<>), 
    typeof(CommandHandlerMediator<>));
```

and referenced like this:

```
public class MessageLogger<TCommand> : ICommandHandler<TCommand>
    where TCommand : <some criteria e.g. MessageCommand>
{
    private ICommandHandler<TCommand> decorated;
    private CommandHandlerMediator<LogCommand> logger;

    public MessageLogger(
        ICommandHandler<TCommand> decorated,
        CommandHandlerMediator<LogCommand> logger)
    {
        this.innerHandler = innerHandler;
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    //....

}
```

One new class and you're sorted for all of your handlers.

Comment: You make a good point about having to check for circular references if the decorator asks for two instances of the abstraction it decorates, but that actually isn't the case in my example. The decorator actually does not decorate just any `ICommandHandler<T>` but rather the very specific `ICommandHandler<MessageCommand>`, which should never be confused with a command handler of a completely different generic type. I'm still not convinced that what I am asking for is unreasonable.

Comment: I could create unrelated interfaces, for instance `IMessageHandler` and `ILoggingHandler`; this would remove any relation of the interfaces from each other and resolve the problem with `RegisterDecorator()`. But again, I would lose some flexibility. One of the reasons I like the generic `ICommandHandler<T>` interface is that you can create generic decorators for any command handler. For instance, I have a `RetryCommandHandler<T>` that catches exceptions thrown by its inner handler and retries it if it appears to be timeout-related. I can't use it if all of my interfaces are completely unique.

Comment: @MattMiller you are absolutely correct, as I said it is an edge case and would require a lot of extra code to enable a very minor feature. The generic command handler abstraction and decorators is an amazing pairing of patterns and enables a multitude of features without any duplicate code. The benefits of the speed and simplicity of Simple Injector over the majority or other containers far outweighs this *minor* inconvenience. I also wonder if any other container can handle this scenario?

Comment: I do have a workaround that's doable, but I was hoping for feedback from a SI dev as to whether this limitation was intentional. Steve, you out there??

Comment: @qujck Yes, Ninject and Windsor can handle this scenario. They don't explicitly define decorators but they allow you to say what they to resolve to based on what type they're injected to.

Comment: @qujck The test you refer to is registering the open generic type, and the decorator does indeed take two parameters of the exact same type. I'm not sure how that applies to my example.

Comment: @MattMiller that's a very good point. There is not a specific enough test to say for sure. We'll review the code and provide an update asap.

Comment: @Kenneth: But Ninject and Windsor can't handle applying decorators conditionally, based on a predicate or generic type constraint. They will fail miserably. This works out-of-the-box with Simple Injector. You win some, you lose some :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can change your Decorator ctor as

```
public MessageLogger(ICommandHandler<MessageCommand> innerHandler)
{
    this.innerHandler = innerHandler;
}
```

to match the neccessary ctor signature with "a single parameter of type ICommandHandler (or Func>)". And inject logger  as a property and not the ctor argument. I didn't work with simple-injector but looking at your exception message it's the most obvious solution, because of decorator constructor signature limitations.

Comment: I don't think changing the design of my classes to suit a DI container is the answer. My current workaround is to explicitly register the decorated type (ICommandHandler<MessageCommand> in the example) with an anonymous function that manually builds the concrete types; similar to the "manual" function, but inside a register call. Not horrible, but I'm wondering why it's necessary.

Comment: Imagine that MessageCommand is derived form LogCommand or wiseversa. When DI call decorator ctor, which argument should it choose to be a decorate target? ICommandHandler<MessageCommand> or ICommandHandler<LogCommand>? It's not that smart to resolve it. And may be [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13435701/simple-injector-open-generic-decorators) help you.

Comment: SimpleInjector knows what type I want to decorate, because it's the first parameter of `RegisterDecorator()`. The link has an unrelated problem.

Comment: @qujck So what you're saying is that there IS a technical limitation, and this isn't really a bug? I can accept that, although I'm not sure how that could be. I'm explicitly telling SI that "hey, this class is a decorator of the closed generic type `ICommandHandler<MessageCommand>` and there is exactly one parameter of that type. Seems like the easiest thing in the world for it to first check each parameter of the constructor for equality with the type I give it. But I don't know the inner workings so I'm not qualified to say, and I'd much rather have a faster container than handle edge cases.

Comment: Just to be clear, I wasn't saying that SI should know the decorated type as the first parameter of the decorator's constructor, I was saying it should know the type because it asks for it as the first parameter of `RegisterDecorator()`.

Comment: Yes i think it's a technical limitation. I agree with you @MattMiller that it seems a bit strange, i mean the limitation(or bug). But it's the fact. Personally i use spring.net with xml config and explicit objects wiring that keep me away of such kind of problems.

Comment: @lavrik: But when using Spring, you'll have two problems of course, since XML configuration is very brittle and its impossible with Spring to apply generic decorators to generic interfaces, let alone applying them conditionally based on predicates or generic type constraints.

Comment: @Steven what do you mean "brittle", and it's possible to instatiate generics in spring. Decorator doesn't matter, just the pattern. There is no separated features for this, you just create objects and connects them in some way. It has AOP but it's another thing. Anyway the question is not about spring.net.

Comment: @lavrik: If you have hundred `ICommandHandler<T>` implementations, and you want to wrap all of them in the same generic `TransactionCommandHandlerDecorator<T>`, how many changes to the config file whould this require?

Comment: Xml configuration is brittle, because there is no compile time support. You will have to change the config manually every time you change the name of a class. No tool support here. btw. You started mentioning Spring.net, not me ;-).

Comment: Yes it's a problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Your solution seems a bit awkward as it is a combination of a decorator and constructor injection/composition (something). While it's not exactly an asnwer to your question, it'll probably solve your problem (in a nicer way I'd say):

```
public class LoggingHandler : ICommandHandler<MessageCommand>
{
    private ICommandHandler<MessageCommand> innerHandler;

    public LoggingHandler(ICommandHandler<MessageCommand> innerHandler)
    {
        this.innerHandler = innerHandler;
    }

    public void Execute(MessageCommand command)
    {
        innerHandler.Execute(command);

        Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Message \"{0}\" sent at {1}",
        command.Message, DateTime.Now));
    }
}
```

I don't see the need for a separate CommandHandler for a LogMessage. You could just log inside the object that decorates your actual commandhandler. What is its purpose otherwise?

With this approach you have a pure decorator, which is a better solution IMO as it saves you two extra classes.

Comment: Keep in mind that this was a trivial example to show the situation. Imagine that there is a lot more going on in the "logging" than Debug.WriteLine(), and that the logging behavior needs to be shared by many other components, and may be a decorated class itself. The ability to model the logging as a command handler also does give real benefits.

Comment: But then it's not a decorator anymore. When you call `RegisterDecorator` it expects to receive a type that `include a single parameter of type ICommandHandler<MessageCommand>` SimpleInjector has probably limitations on how decorators are build. You can do this with a more advanced container such as Ninject, but if you want a pure decorator configuration, you'll have to use a pure decorator.

Comment: It seems natural to me to have a decorator that has other dependencies. I certainly wouldn't say it's "No longer a decorator". The problem in my question only arises when the other dependency is the same generic type (`ICommandHandler<>`). If, for instance, the MessageLogger asked for a `Logger` instead of a `ICommandHandler<LogCommand>`, it works - but the decorator loses flexibility, because now you are forced to use that specific `Logger` type.

Comment: @Kenneth decorators would be severely limited (i.e. a bit pointless!) if they were not able to accept other parameters in their constructor. This "limitation" is by design - decorators are usually intended to apply cross cutting concerns, so in the example above would normally decorate multiple `ICommandHandlers<>`.