# Reprinting from an application with Command/Decorator Pattern and Simple Injector

Tags: c#, decorator, simple-injector

So i am using a decorator to print after certain commands are handled. My issue is if the user wants to issue a reprint. I created a `Reprint` command class that gets sent from the UI layer, but the `Reprint` command does not need a separate handler from the `PrintDecorator` since the reprint handling is exactly everything in the print decorator. Is there a strategy to target the `PrintDecorator` only with `SimpleInjector`? I know this probably goes against the pattern, but the only way I could think of was to create an empty command handler for the reprint command, but that does not seem right. Thanks.

```
  public class Reprint : ICommandParam, IPrintFrom
  {
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Printer { get; set; }
    public int Copies { get; set; }
  }

  public class PrintDecorator<TCommand> : ICommandHandler<TCommand>
    where TCommand : IPrintFrom
  {
    private readonly IFooService _svc;
    private readonly ICommandHandler<TCommand> _handler;

    public PrintDecorator(IFooService svc, ICommandHandler<TCommand> handler)
    {
      if (svc == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("IFooService");

      _svc = svc;
      _handler = handler;
    }

    [Import] // optional
    public IDatabase Database { get; set; }

    public void Handle(TCommand commandParm)
    {
      if (_handler != null)
        _handler.Handle(commandParm);

      svc.GetDataFromService(commandParm.id);
      svc.PrintData(commandParm.Printer, commandParm.Copies);    
      if (Database != null && commandParm.Copies > 0) {
        // TODO - add a print record
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I find your null checks a bit scary. Why is it valid for your decorator to have no database or no decoratee? In general you should prevent invalid state by injecting all required dependencies in the contructor and adding guard statements in there. This prevents your code from getting complicated with null checks.

Comment: About those 'optional dependencies', please take a look at [this article of mine](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=97) that explains why "Dependencies should hardly ever be optional".

Comment: For the null checks, the idea was that Database is required only if printing is tracked, which in my mind was optional. I originally checked the handler as being null because I thought I could use the `Reprint` command directly with the decorator and no handler, that I can remove now.

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on what you want. My suggestion is to keep the reprinting logic inside a real `ReprintCommandHandler` (probably by injecting a service that does the printing the same way you would do with the decorator). This seems reasonable to me, because in the case of reprinting, the reprinting is the actual business logic, and not a cross-cutting concern.

In this case you will have to exclude the `PrintDecorator` from being decorated around your `ReprintCommandHandler` and this can be done as follows:

```
container.RegisterDecorator(
    typeof(ICommandHandler<>),
    typeof(PrintDecorator<>),
    c => c.ServiceType != typeof(ICommandHandler<Reprint>));
```

If on the other hand, you want to keep the printing logic inside the `PrintDecorator` without having to duplicate this logic inside your business layer, you can either implement a completely empty `ReprintCommandHandler`, or you can register a special [Null Object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) command handler.

Using the empty handler is of course Simple and will make your configuration really straightforward:

```
// NOTE: Use RegisterManyForOpenGeneric for Simple Injector v2.x
container.Register(typeof(ICommandHandler<>),
   new[] { typeof(ICommandHandler<>).Assembly });

container.RegisterDecorator(
    typeof(ICommandHandler<>),
    typeof(PrintDecorator<>));
```

Downside is of course that you need an empty class for this. So the alternative is to implement the Null Object pattern as follows:

```
public class NullCommandHandler<T> : ICommandHandler<T> {
    public void Handle(T command) { }
}
```

This implementation can be reused in case you have multiple empty implementations and you can register this as follows:

```
// NOTE: Use RegisterManyForOpenGeneric for Simple Injector v2.x
container.Register(typeof(ICommandHandler<>),
   new[] { typeof(ICommandHandler<>).Assembly });

container.Register<ICommandHandler<Reprint>, NullCommandHandler<Reprint>>();

container.RegisterDecorator(
    typeof(ICommandHandler<>),
    typeof(PrintDecorator<>));
```

Comment: If there is no extra logic for the reprint outside of the decorator, it seems I have to create an empty `ReprintCommandHandler` or `SimpleInjector` will tell me there is not registration for `ICommandHandler<Reprint>` because right now I do not have a handler for the `Reprint` class and was going to rely just on the decorator. Did I understand you correctly?

Comment: @JayMichael: I'm sorry. My answer wasn't very clear. Please see my update.

Comment: hmm that gives me something to think about. I have used the Null Object Pattern in the past with success, but maybe putting the actual printing logic in a service that the handlers use may be better for the future. Thanks for the help @Steven

Comment: @JayMichael: That seems very SOLID to me. My decorators often don't do much more than delegating the call to an injected service. It doesn't have to be this way, but often I want to reuse the same logic (across decorators and parts of the system) and in that case it deserves to be extracted into a separate service.

Comment: Thanks. would it be frowned upon to take out `IFooService` and instead bring in my `IDispatcher` and have that call the reprint command handler from the decorator? (e.g. `_dispatcher.Dispatch(new Reprint()`). The `IDispatcher` is used in the web layer to send commands and queries off to their handlers.

Comment: i only say that because the service that I ended up creating does the printing in three methods: get the data via a web service, print what is finds and optionally track it. So the decorator and the printing handler would have to call these 3 methods, so I thought I would call the printing handler from the decorator

Comment: @JayMichael: Some people might frown upon that. I like to prevent multiple command handlers from running during one transaction; for me the handler is the transactional boundary. But others think differently about this. So that's up to you. Do what you think is most maintainable in the long run. Also [this q/a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22563530/simple-injector-register-decorator-with-another-dependency-of-same-generic-typ) might interest you.